# Método de login em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando fazer um login com Ruby, porém está apresentando o erro

```
undefined local variable or method `login' for #<Object:0x00000000059ccea8> (NameError)
```

Montei a classe:

```
class  Login <SitePrism::Page 
    element :username_fild, "input[placeholder='Username']"
    element :password_fild, "input[placeholder='Password']"
    element :Login_buton,   "input[title='Log In']"

    def Login (nome, senha)
        username_fild.set(nome)
        password_fild.set(nome)
        Login_button.click
    end 

end
```

e passei a variável:

```
Dado("que esteja na tela de cadastro do SuiteCRM") do
    Home.new.load
    @login = login.new
    @login.load
    @login.login("will","will")

  end
```

quando executo gera o erro:

```
undefined local variable or method `login' for #<Object:0x00000000059ccea8> (NameError)
```

Alguém consegue ajudar para solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 2):

Antes de começar, lembre-se de sempre seguir as *guidelines* e as convenções da linguagem, ainda mais ao utilizar o framework Ruby on Rails, que é conhecido pelo paradigma de design [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). Nomes de métodos sempre em `snake_case_minusculo` e classes/módulos em `PascalCase`.

Vejamos a mensagem de erro:

```
undefined local variable or method `login' for #<Object:0x00000000059ccea8> (NameError)
```

Isso quer dizer que você tentou utilizar `.login` em um objeto, do tipo `Object`, que não possui esse método. Isso gera um `NameError`. No seu código, pode ver que você chamou `.login`, onde deveria ser `.Login`, já que definiu dessa maneira.

E quando você instancia a classe `Login`, deve ser `Login.new` e não `login.new`.

Lembre-se das convenções!